# Element difference of a list inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with lists inside one of the columns (LOG_TIMES), how can I create a new column with the time differences (in seconds) of the list elements?

```
    DATE_RECORDED           PERSON  LOG_TIMES
0   2018-03-22 11:58:23.585 JOHN    [15/03/2018 10:30:48, 15/03/2018 10:29:48, ...
1   2018-03-22 11:58:23.585 JOHN    [20/03/2018 14:28:36, 20/03/2018 14:26:36, ...
```

The expected output would be the datafame with a column displaying the time differences (values in seconds):

```
    DATE_RECORDED           PERSON  LOG_TIMES
0   2018-03-22 11:58:23.585 JOHN    [60, ...
1   2018-03-22 11:58:23.585 JOHN    [120, ...
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: @HarvIpan just edited the question!

Comment: It would have been nice if you could post actual values rather than hypothetical ones.

Comment: @HarvIpan just changed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `df`:

```
                 DATE_RECORDED PERSON                                                        LOG_TIMES
0  2018-03-22 11:58:23.585   JOHN                       [15/03/2018 10:30:48, 15/03/2018 10:29:48]
1  2018-03-22 11:58:23.585   JOHN  [20/03/2018 14:28:36, 20/03/2018 14:26:36, 20/03/2018 14:26:30]
```

You need:

```
df['LOG_TIMES'] = df['LOG_TIMES'].apply(lambda x: list(pd.Series([dt.datetime.strptime(y.strip(), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') for y in x[1:-1].split(',')]).diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').dropna().mul(-1)))
```

Output:

```
    DATE_RECORDED PERSON       LOG_TIMES
0  2018-03-22 11:58:23.585   JOHN         [60.0]
1  2018-03-22 11:58:23.585   JOHN  [120.0, 6.0]
```

If `df['LOG_TIMES']` already a list of `datetime` objects, you can simply use:

```
df['LOG_TIMES'].apply(lambda x: list(pd.Series(x).diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').dropna().mul(-1)))
```

Comment: This returned me: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Is `type(df['LOG_TIMES'][0])` `list`?

Comment: I think it is. I usually stay away from questions like this where OP clearly has not made an effort to make it easy to understand or solve their problem. Either ignore, or in worse cases, vote to close. Saves everyone the headache.

Comment: Some users only paste their code, some only their data, and other still post neither. Questions with _both_ are the best because you can visualise OP's problem and understand what it is they were trying to do by the code they posted.

Comment: @coldspeed, seems like I should stay away from such questions or ask about much clarification in the comment section before I spend time solving it.

Comment: I always like questions with input/ output/ expectedoutput and code. It makes my life easier.

Comment: Thanks @HarvIpan your solution worked just fine, I just had to make a few type conversions.